# center text with variable python3.6

Tags: python, formatting, centering

First, I am new to programming in general, so that means I'm new to python as well, so type slowly so I can keep up. 
I am trying to center a line of text that includes a variable that was input by a user. Something like this:

```
age = input ("How old are you? ")    
print ("{: ^80}".format("You are", (age), "years old."))
```

I've tried as many ways as I can think of to get this to center the entire line reading . . . 
You are 40 years old. (Assuming, of course, the user input = 40)
with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: `print('You are {} years old'.format(age).center(80))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .center() on strings will pad them with spaces on both sides.

```
print('You are {} years old'.format(age).center(80))
```

Comment: @zvone's comment inspired this answer :)

Comment: Hadus, thank you. That worked exactly as I was hoping.

Comment: Thank @zvone I merely made his comment into an answer. But thanks anyhow!